# Arduino When keep pressing button a continuous Letter is show

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

First of all sorry for my weak English

I have Arduino Leonardo
and I have a push-button ok?

When I click the button the letter 'W' is printed to the notepad
ok?

**I Want when I keep holding the button the 'w' Letter is printed
why? like in games when I keep holding on 'W' letter the player will move, then when I release my finger the player will stop.**
Please please please I need your help because I'm a beginner

This is my code

```
#include "Keyboard.h"

const int buttonPin = 4;          // input pin for pushbutton
int previousButtonState = HIGH;   // for checking the state of a pushButton

void setup() {
  // make the pushButton pin an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  // initialize control over the keyboard:
  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // read the pushbutton:
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // if the button state has changed,
  if ((buttonState != previousButtonState)
      // and it's currently pressed:
      && (buttonState == HIGH)) {
    // type out a message
    Keyboard.print("W");
  }
  // save the current button state for comparison next time:
  previousButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

Comment: Also asked at https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=662835

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the reason why your code only acts as if the button was pressed once are the following lines

```cpp
// if the button state has changed,
  if ((buttonState != previousButtonState)
      // and it's currently pressed:
      && (buttonState == HIGH)) {
```

so, this will only be true once after the button gets pressed. If you remove the previous state check and only check if the button is currently high it will trigger a press every time your programm loops. This will have side effects though, like a short press will likely trigger multiple times.

Fortunately, there is another function provided by the keyboard library to solve this issue: `Keyboard.press()`

> When called, Keyboard.press() functions as if a key were pressed and held on your keyboard. Useful when using modifier keys. To end the key press, use Keyboard.release() or Keyboard.releaseAll().
>   https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/keyboardpress/

So, if you modify your code like this:

```cpp
void loop() {
  // read the pushbutton:
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // if the button state has changed,
  if (buttonState != previousButtonState){
    if( buttonState == HIGH ) {
      Keyboard.press('w');
    }else{
      Keyboard.release('w');
    }
  }
  // save the current button state for comparison next time:
  previousButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

it will act exactly as if the keyboard button keeps beeing pressed.

Please note that currently the script will likely act as if the button is pressed a few times per press because of bouncing. You could fix this issue by adding a small delay after the button press and release part. This will give the button time to settle to the new state. Read more about bouncing here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-4/contact-bounce/

Comment: I Added your Loop but when I click the button the letter 'W' just keeps printed it cannot stop until I unplug the Arduino.